# Rails 3: has_many through query

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, has-many-through

I have these three Active Record models:

```
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :event_categories, inverse_of: :event
  has_many :categories, through: :event_categories
end

class EventCategory < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :event
  belongs_to :category
end

class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :event_categories
  has_many :events, through: :event_categories
end
```

I think the relations are good.

If I want to know what Events have a Category, for example id=5.. I do:

```
Category.find(5).events
```

But, if I want to know all Events for more than one category, for example:

```
Category.where(:id => [3,5]).events
```

It isn't working. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please note, when you do `has_many :events` in a model, Active Record defines a method of name `events` for that class.

When you do `Category.find(5).events`, you get `events` associated with one object (i.e. `Category.find(5)`) , however `Category.where(:id => [3,5])` returns an array of `Category` objects, so you can't use  `events` function on an array, Only way to get  `events` for all search results is iterate over them and access them individually, something like following:

```
 all_events = Category.where(:id => [3,5]).inject([]) {|res,cat| res << cat.events}
```

Above code will do one query per iteration, to avoid this, we can include `events`, in the first query itself, like following, which will provide result in only one query:

```
 all_events = Category.includes(:events).where(:id => [3,5]).inject([]) {|res,cat| res << cat.events}
```

Comment: Thank! but I ask me if this solution do a lot of queries?

Comment: @user1364684: updated the answer, does this answer your query??

Comment: and do you know how I could do for get unique events? I've a case in that an event maybe twice

Comment: 'all_events.uniq' should be sufficient, not sure, how can you get from these kind of query pattern.